# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getPro()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have been debugging this issue.
However, I cannot figure out the solution.

**Here's the error:**

[image: Error - Index.php]

**My code:**

[image: Index.php]

**Then my functions:**

[image: functions.php]

I hope you can help with my problem, the code was given by my proctor.
But it does not work.

Comment: Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` your `functions.php` file into the `index.php` file.

Add the following at the start of your file.

```
<?php include('functions.php'); ?>
```

see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: it would be `<?php include('functions.php'); ?>` (you forgot to close the string), also as you see in the post, the script fails if the file is not loaded, so the best option here is not `include()`, is `require()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: It does not work both INCLUDE and REQUIRE.

Comment: Did you insert it before or after calling the method `getPro()` ?

Comment: I see, there is a syntax error on your `funciton getBrands()`, so you are opening the `while loop` but you are not closing it. try to closing it after line 20 on your `functions.php`. Basically `getPro()` function is currently inside `getBrands()`.

Comment: Yes, I inserted the include before the getpro.
I already closed the function and relocate but stlll not luck :(

Comment: PHP errors can be really inaccurate when they tell where the error is happening. PHP errors tell where the parser could not continue, not where the mistaking syntax is, so you better don't trust so much in these error lines indications. For example, forget a semicolon and you will get the error in the next line, not in the one that you forgot the semicolon in. So please provide us the full code to check if more errors like this exist.

Comment: You should share the code of index.php and functions.php file so that if there are any other mistakes, that can be removed.

Comment: Hi! I already posted new ANSWER above with the fullcode and screenshot.